# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied Exception

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to do a simple program for RMI. But, I'm getting the following exception while running the line
   Naming.rebind("interfacename",Remoteserverobject);

> java.security.AccessControlException:
>   access denied
>   (java.net.SocketPermission
>   127.0.0.1:1099 connect,resolve)

My Code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if(System.getSecurityManager()==null)
        {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
        Remoteserver objremoteserver=new Remoteserver();
        objremoteserver.setmsg("Hello! How are you?");
        System.out.println(objremoteserver.getmsg());
        try
        {
        Naming.rebind("Remotemethod", objremoteserver);
        System.out.println("Server Started");
        }
        catch(RemoteException re)
        {
            System.out.println(re.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Unknown Exception Occured!!!!");
        }
    }
```

How to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i guess this works

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Remoteserver objremoteserver=new Remoteserver();
        objremoteserver.setmsg("Hello! How are you?");
        System.out.println(objremoteserver.getmsg());
        try
        {
        Naming.rebind("Remotemethod", objremoteserver);
        System.out.println("Server Started");
        }
        catch(RemoteException re)
        {
            System.out.println(re.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Unknown Exception Occured!!!!");
        }
    }
```

Every JRE has a default security manager, U r trying to override with a new security manager. You dint specify any properties to this new security manager.so the error.The solution is use the default manager are create a completely new security manager following these [instructions](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html).

Comment: Wrong in every possible way. A JVM doesn't run under a security manager unless you tell it to. The RMISecurityManager doesn't have any properties to be set, so their absence does not explain anything. The instruction to both 'use the default manager' and 'create a completely new security manager' is self-contradictory, and this answer is therefore meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a security manager unless (i) you know you need one and (ii) you have written an appropriate .policy file. If you think both these apply, run your problem with -Djava.security.debug=access,failure to see what is really going wrong. Most likely you haven't granted yourself the required permission or you haven't specified the policy file location correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have setup the RMISecurityManager as explained [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/client.html)

Comment: S. I included that line. It is creating new rmisecurity manager. But, no use.

Comment: S.. I posted. Can u check that?